# How to handle user customizable website themes?

Tags: php, mysql, css, content-management-system, themes

We are developing a CMS and would like advice on the best way to handle user customizable themes. We have a couple ideas but are not really sure what the best approach is. The CMS will allow the user to customize every part of the site including colors, fonts, layout, etc, through a theme editor UI built into the CMS.

We were thinking writing a custom CSS parser that writes changes out to a CSS file for that theme. This approach seems like it may have a lot of point of failure and a lot of overheard.

The other way was to store all the CSS in a database and then just use inline CSS.

The CMS has been built using JQuery and PHP with MySQL database for user information and content, but not CSS.

Is there a more efficient way to parse/control/edit CSS properties of the theme?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to take a look at the way [WordPress](http://www.wordpress.org) or any other pre-built platform (Drupal, Joomla, etc.) approaches this. WordPress themes consist of template files stored on the file system that allow users to have complete control over the look and feel of their Web site. The CSS for each theme is stored in a file called `style.css`. WP itself does not enforce a frontend layout but instead leaves that in the hands of the site administrator/developer.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. We are trying to create CMS where a user does not have to edit or touch the bare code. Instead they customize everything with CMS (colors, contents, backgrounds) with drag and drop and buttons. We would like to know what is the most efficient way to control/edit and save CSS properties after the user has made some changes... In WordPress, if you want to create your own custom theme from the original, you have to have a knowledge of CSS and HTML. We are trying to eliminate that.

Comment: I agree. I am trying to achieve the same effect for the end-user

Answer (score 0):

I would treat your CSS files as if they were code classes.  For instance, have a CSS file for your customizable font themes, one for page themes etc.

With that in mind, on page load you can easily build a dynamic CSS file based on user selections.

AKA

font1.css
font2.css
font3.css

page1.css
page2.css
page3.css

On Page load you identify that user preferences are font 1 and page 2, pull in both css files and walla you're good to go!

Comment: it is pretty interesting approach, however I believe the user is still limited to what CMS provides due to the "hard-coded" themes. I am trying to achieve a full freedom for the end-user. I know it is possible, since there are many programs that allow users to build their sites freely. I was hoping that the same could be achieved through web interface.

Comment: You could absolutely open it up to more than just hard coded themes if you prefer but the draw back with that is you could potentially open yourself up to Security holes (running user code).  If you're comfortable with protecting against that then go for it.  A nice middle ground may be using LESS and allowing the user to only modify the variables within your LESS class but not add or remove any.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently looking to do the same thing.  Some of the solutions I've come across seem to use an xml file for the layout and then (probably) parse out a custom css file.  This way, the layout determines the "stacking order" of page content modules and the other customizable features (which are usually limited) such as fonts, colors & background image are handled by an additional custom (user)css file.

I'll be following this one and will also be interested in finding actual code solutions to making it happen.  For instance how to use jquery to build a draggable content module interface for the user backend.

Comment: Currently I am developing an approach to editing CSS file. It requires a schema where all element properties follow some rules. For instance, width and height are always first if applicable, position is next, then effects such as border, background... etc... This allows me to build a parser that will follow this schema. However, no custom-made CSS files can be imported or parsed by the PHP since it will break the schema. The reason for this is to lower the workload for the browser. I don't know how it will work out